How to run React-Native-Expo App and Laravel by using Homestead
I'm working on an react-native-app with expo which is supposed to get data from an laravel based api. The laravel-application is running on a virtula machine by using homestead.
Now I want to fetch some data:
const MoviesScreen= () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
         const response = await axios.get('https://mylaravelapp.test/api/movies');
         setData(response.data);
         setLoading(false);
      } catch (err) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', err);
        setError(err.message);
        setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  fetchData();
 }, []);

 const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <ListItem bottomDivider>
      <ListItem.Content>
        <ListItem.Title>{item.name}</ListItem.Title>
        <ListItem.Subtitle>{item.version}</ListItem.Subtitle>
      </ListItem.Content>
   </ListItem>
 );

 if (loading) {
    return (
     <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" />
     </View>
    );
 }

 if (error) {
   return (
     <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
       <Text>Error fetching data</Text>
     </View>
   );
 }

 return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, paddingTop: 50 }}>
      <FlatList
         data={data}
         renderItem={renderItem}
         keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
         ListEmptyComponent={<Text>No movies found</Text>}
      />
   </View>
  );
};

export default MoviesScreen;

When I run my react-native-expo app, or this screen in particular, I get this error:
Error fetching data: [AxiosError: Network Error]

After some investigation, I know it has something to do my virtual machine e.g. the homestead setup, apparently because it not generates some IP, where I could grab the data, like for example 127.0.0.1:5000/api/movies.
So, how can I make this work by still using homestead instead of switching to xampp and running php artisan serve?

Is this both local? Did you add the ip address/host name in your hosts file?

when adding ip addres/host in your hosts file, try to ping first what the result of https://mylaravelapp.test

@Mr.Kenneth Yes, I've added the ipaddress/host name to my host file and when I ping, the result is: 64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.133 ms etc. etc.

just to confirm you added 127.0.0.1 mylaravelapp.test below other ip/hostname pair right? Then issue might be on different part. Can you access 127.0.0.1:5000/api/movies in postman or browser? Does it return the same errors?

If it returns the same errors, problem might be with laravel, If no errors, then problem is in react-native's axios settings. Probably
